# jQuery Autocomplete (1.8.5) - Uncaught TypeError, property 'source' is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am attempting to use the jQuery autocomplete widget which I have used previously on earlier versions of jQuery.

With the code I'm currently using (and jQuery UI 1.8.5) I am getting the following error when typing a letter in the initialised autocomplete input field:

```
jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js:320Uncaught TypeError: Property 'source' of object #<an Object> is not a function
```

The autocomplete code is basically the jQuery example documentation (added to my page with other JS on it):

```
<input type="text" id="example" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = "Core Selectors Attributes Traversing Manipulation CSS Events Effects Ajax Utilities".split(" ");
    $("#example").autocomplete(data);
</script>
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that should be:

```
$("#example").autocomplete({ source: data });
```

Comment: Great! Thank you - so documentation is out-of-date.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to call [the autocomplete widget in jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)
the same way that the deprecated [autocomplete jQuery plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) was called. The entire API is different, so take a look at [the migration guide](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide), but your example would be

```
$("#example").autocomplete({ source: data });
```